# Does polymorphism refer to methods or objects?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

So I am a beginner to Java and while reading a book, and I had a question about polymorphism. It seems that there are two distinct meanings of polymorphism: one being the polymorphic nature of inheritance hierarchies (like type compatibility), and the other being choosing the right method to call during runtime, as different levels of inheritance may have different overridden methods. Which one do people refer to when talking about polymorphism? Or is it a general umbrella term for both?

An example of type compatibility would be something like

```
Animal a = new Mammal();
```

Or

```
ArrayList<Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<Animal>();
animalList.add(0, new Mammal());
animalList.add(1, new Vertebrate());
```

whereas dynamically binded method selection at runtime is like

```
Student s = null;
Student g = new Graduate();
Student u = new UnderGrad();
... (after reading user input, call a method based on what the user chooses)
if(inputstr.equals("g"))
     s = g;
else if(inputstr.equals("u"))
     s = u;
else
     s = new Student();
s.displayGrade(); //this method is different based on if they are undergrad, grad, or student
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference here - could you provide an example?

Comment: Those examples are the same, or rather, the first is a subset of the second. In both cases, you're referring to a subclass insurance via a superclass reference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We do refer both as Polymorphism. Reason being, The term 'poly' means 'Many' and 'Morpheus' is existence. It just means that, anything that can exist in many forms is tend to have Polymorphism.

> the other being choosing the right method to call during runtime, as
>   different levels of inheritance may have different overridden methods.

In the beginning, We used to term only the method calling as Polymorphism. But because of the evolution in Java, we have new things in store one of which being,

```
ArrayList<Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<Animal>();
animalList.add(0, new Mammal());
animalList.add(1, new Vertebrate());
```

which explains your

> one being the polymorphic nature of inheritance hierarchies (like type
>   compatibility),

The latter one is also polymorphic in nature. *[There are certain limitations to this, as you are beginner you can dig deeper into this. **References**: Head First Java]*

**Answer to the question** would be "Polymorphism is to an Object not method". A method has nothing to do with Polymorphism. A Object has method inside it. *[Hypothetical,Just for your understanding]* . During  runtime, JVM decides which one to call. Please go through the book i told you. Would help you for sure.

Comment: That's not the evolution in Java. One has always been able to pass a subclass instance to a method taking a superclass reference.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, I was referring to the collections stuff, all this cannot be used however we want. there is generics in place. This is possible only in Arrays. If it comes to ArrayList, it depends on how we defined generics.

Answer (score -1):

Polymorphic behaviour applies to object not for methods